# 26 A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-localdb

Не удается воспроизвести подключение к базе данных.

*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)*

Строка подключения:

```
<connectionstrings>
  <add name="DatabaseContext" connectionstring="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB.;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\DatabaseContext.mdf';Integrated Security=True;" providername="System.Data.SqlClient"/
</connectionstrings>
```

Осуществлял пункты по https://stackoverflow.com/a/18060818/8548885 но ничего не помогло.

Как разрешить этот вопрос?

Comment: для начала уберите точку после `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB`

Comment: Замечено, не помогло.

Comment: это какой-то шаблонный проект? строку подключения сами составляли?

Comment: Верно, самостоятельно. Но ранее пытался через контекст вызывать базовый конструктор с наименованием подключения, результат тот же.